# Deploy Acumatica Framework Tools fails

Tags: frameworks, acumatica

I am trying to Deploy Acumatica Framework Tools using the Framework Configuration Wizard and I getting the following error:
Exception occurred while installing resources.

Inner Exception:
 Can't find the Visual Studio template items location.

I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise running on Windows 10 Pro. Both are up to date. 
Any ideas on how to correct this. I’m going to the Acumatica Summit next week and need to do the T100 and T200 course.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wizard is likely looking for the VS2015 registry folder. Until installers are fixed to check in the VS2017 location I recommend you create the VS2015 registry folders with these 4 dummy string keys pointing to VS2017 folder.

The key values in the picture below  point to the default VS2017 folders. I tested this workaround a couple months ago on a colleague computer and we experience no ill effects:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but I could not change my registry due to company policy. My regedit.exe was unavailable:

[image]

So, to fix this issue I installed **[Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/)** . 
That fixed the issue.
Do not forget to restart your computer after installation, otherwise - you will get the same error.  If you solve this problem with installation of VS2015, you will be able to use Visual Studio Template
[image]
in VS2015 only. It will not be available in other versions of Visual Studio.